# Maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling an object

Tags: python

I get the error "maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object".

My object is the following:

```
import numpy as np


class BoundingBox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BoundingBox, self).__init__()
        self.topLeft = np.matrix([0, 0])
        self.topRight = np.matrix([0, 0])
        self.bottomLeft = np.matrix([0, 0])
        self.bottomRight = np.matrix([0, 0])

    @property
    def topLeft(self):
        return self._topLeft

    @topLeft.setter
    def topLeft(self, value):
        self._topLeft = value


    @property
    def topRight(self):
        return self._topRight

    @topRight.setter
    def topRight(self, value):
        self._topRight = value


    @property
    def bottomLeft(self):
        return self._bottomLeft

    @bottomLeft.setter
    def bottomLeft(self, value):
        self._bottomLeft = value


    @property
    def bottomRight(self):
        return self._bottomRight

    @bottomRight.setter
    def bottomRight(self, value):
        self._bottomRight = value
```

It seems that this issue comes from setters but I do not understand why.

Comment: 1. Show us how to generate the error: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
2. Since the bounding box is a rectangle, you should only store two points, not four.  Then write the getters and setters to work with these two points.

Comment: Try test = BoundingBox()

Comment: Works fine; perhaps you left our an underscore in a copy of your code?

Comment: This is a bug in `intellij` : i see it appearing occasionally (but consistently once it starts) on some `pandas` programs

Answer (score 0):

I restart my IDE (PyCharm) and it does work... I don't know why.